# Web API put method keep returning 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Using C# web api, i created a web api that update the information.

```
// Update
// URI PUT + api/Gender/id
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult PutGender(int id, [FromBody] Gender g)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var query = (from gen in genders
                 where gen.Id == id
                 select gen).FirstOrDefault();

    if (query == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("wrong");
    }

    query.Description = g.Description;
    query.LanguageId = g.LanguageId;
    query.InternalCode = g.InternalCode;
    query.isActive = g.isActive;
    query.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I am testing through fiddler and this is how i ran the thing:

URL `http://localhost:49625/API/PutGender`
Action `PUT`
Request Header

```
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:49625
Content-Length: 86
```

RequestBody

```
{"Id":1,"Description":"Undecided","LanguageId":null,"InternalCode":0,"isActive":false}
```

Comment: Is the `id` parameter expected to be passed in the URL as opposed to the body? Does `http://localhost:49625/API/PutGender/1` also give 404?

Comment: Yes it does gives 404 also, i have visual studio 2013, just to inform you

Comment: How are you calling the method? In other words, what is your client application?

Comment: I am using fiddler at the moment, http/1.1 under the compose tab, i haven't implemented a client side for this method still learning asp.net

Comment: And you have set the method in Fiddler to PUT?

Comment: Also, what routes have you defined?

Comment: Correct I have set to put, now i am not to sure what u mean by routes, i used to be able to update it using void method, but i understand it doesn't follow properly http standard

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `id` parameter?

Comment: I have try removing the id, but I notice when i call i get this response {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49625/API/PutGender'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'PutGender'."}

Comment: Hang on a moment, you are missing the name of the controller in the URL. For example, if your controller is called `GenderController` the URL would be `http://localhost:49625/API/Gender/PutGender`

Comment: OMG, as if i didn't see this thank you, oh was going nuts, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is missing the name of the controller. For example, if your controller is called `GenderController` then the URL should be `http://localhost:49625/API/Gender/PutGender`

Answer (score 0):

For other people that might run into this problem (myself included). Also check your route configuration. If you are using the default route configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

There is no need to specify the "action part" of your url (PutGender), "PUT http://myhost/api/gender/1" should be fine. Also, if your method is named Put...Something, I am pretty sure you can omit the [HttpPut] attribute from the method signature aswell.